# Solving a 4th order ODE (BVP)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am trying to solve the ODE of a beam on an elastic foundation

$ \frac{d^4w(x)}{dx^4} + 4\beta^4 w(x) = q(x) = 0 $,

where $\beta^4 = \frac{k}{4EI}$ is a constant.

The BCs are $w(0)=0$, $w'(0)=0$, $w'(l)=0$ and $EIw'''(l)=-V$.

The general solution is

$w(x) = e^{\beta x} (c_1 cos(\beta x) + c_2 sin(\beta x) ) + e^{-\beta x} (c_3 cos(\beta x) + c_4 sin(\beta x) ) $

When I start to differentiate the general solution to match it with my BCs, the results just get too complicated, and I can't manage to simplify them to get the constants $c_1$ to $c_4$. Is there a simpler way to find the constants?

Thank you!

Update:

There is an example I have found where the hom. equation is solved for an infinite beam:

[image: Solution from a book]

They use some sort of ansatz, but I do not get how they have come up with that, and why is it correct to solve it this way in the first place. Could we use a similar method for the equation posted above?

Comment: You could use the hyperbolic functions instead of the exponentials to get more structure in the left boundary.

Comment: I have tried that, too. The calculation is however still a huge mess

Comment: Yes. Another idea is to replace all the cosine terms with the sine to $(l-x)$, as $\sin(βx)$ and $\sin(β(l-x))$ still are independent except for a discrete set of $l$ values, the hyperbolic variants are independent for $l>0$.

Comment: Why is it $sin(\beta(l-x))$ and not $sin(\beta(x+\pi/2))$?

Comment: Because that way some terms also get automatically zero on the right boundary.

Comment: But why is it allowed to just equate $sin(\beta (l-x))$ with $cos(\beta x)$? $l-x$ would suggest we have shifted sine to the right by $l$. If I use the method you suggest, I get $c_1(e^{2\beta l}-3)=c_2$. My equation for $w'(x)=c_1\beta[e^{\beta x}cos(\beta x)+e^{-\beta x}cos(\beta x) -e^{\beta x}sin(\beta x) + 3 e^{-\beta x}sin(\beta x) ] +c_2 \beta [...]$ is still unwieldy.

Comment: I did not say that they are equal, I said that in most cases these are as well a solution basis. Apply trigonometric identities to identify the basis transformation.